# Resolving super-class constraints in a static form

Tags: haskell, typeclass, constraint-kinds

I want to write a typeclass for types that have a static pointer to a dictionary that can discharge the super class constraints. In this contrived example the super-constraint is `Typeable`, since modern GHC versions automatically provides the instance for all types.

In reality, the super-constraints are non-trivial and instances of `Static a` allow the dictionaries of those constraints to be serialized, since `forall a. StaticPtr a` can be serialized.

First, the following code compiles without issue,

```
{-# LANGUAGE StaticPointers #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecideableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import GHC.StaticPtr
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Lifting
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)

class Typeable a => Static a where
    sdict :: Dict (Static a)

-- The 'Typeable f' constraint should be trivial, but typechecking 
-- fails without it. Is it possible to get rid of it, if not then why?
instance (Typeable f, Lifting Static f, Static a) => Static (f a) where
    sdict = Dict \\ lifting @Static @f @a
```

But when I write the class in the desired way using static pointers,

```
class Typeable a => Static a where
    sdict :: StaticPtr (Dict (Static a))

instance (Typeable f, Lifting Static f, Static a) => Static (f a) where
    sdict = static (Dict \\ lifting @Static @f @a)
```

GHC complains about type applications in the body of a static form:

```
Only identifiers of top-level bindings can appear in the body of the static form:
  static (Dict \\ lifting @Static @f @a)
but the following identifiers were found instead: f a
```

Then I tried to let GHC resolve the instances entirely on its own, without using `Lifting` to guide the typechecker

```
instance (Typeable f, Static a) => Static (f a) where sdict = static Dict
```

But this fails as well,

```
• No instance for (Static a) arising from a use of ‘Dict’                                    
• In the body of a static form: Dict                                                                 
  In the expression: static Dict
  In an equation for ‘sdict’: sdict = static Dict
```

A more monomorphic instance also fails with a very similar error: `No instance for (Static a)`,

```
instance Static a => Static [a] where sdict = static Dict
```

This led me to learn more about how GHC's typeclass instance resolution works: a class's super-constraints are not applied until after the instance is actually resolved. But GHC was able to satisfy `Dict :: Static a => Dict (Static a)` in the first example, which clearly requires a `Static a` instance to be in scope.

Any suggestions how to write this, if it's even possible? Hopefully someone with more experience with the [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html) package can provide the right contortions to satisfy the typechecker.

Comment: This isn't a `constraints` related issue. This is an issue with the magic behind `static`. As its name suggests, `static` needs to take something whose value can be computed statically. That means it either needs to be a top-level binding, or something derived from top-level bindings. This simply isn't possible.